# Raspberry Pi sound

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am trying to configure the linux software festival which converts text to voice on a Raspberry Pi.

Before and after the sound is played there is glitch sound that is heard.

Does anyone know what is causing this glitch noise?

How can I get rid of this?

It seems like it is the Raspberry Pi that is causing the problem, because I got the same problem with espeak.

Would it be better using HDMI?

This guy has the same glitch sound when he is playing sounds. Forward to 3:18 in the video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=br-xyW8iccg&feature=fvsr

Comment: I don't know why I deserved the down vote for having a problem?

Comment: the audio jack on the Pi is just awful.  you need to use HDMI or a USB sound card to make it bearable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read on another forum that it could be the sample rate that caused the problem. I tried playing a regular wav-file but I got the same noise before and after.

The only solution to the problem I have found is using HDMI. No noise is heard then.

At this site the author writes that the sound driver for Raspberry Pi is still in a beta version, so hopefully the problem will be fixed with a later version.

http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-audio/

Also found this that can be of help.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#Pops_When_Starting_and_Stopping_Playback

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3626/how-to-get-better-audio-quality-from-audio-jack-output

Comment: The problem was fixed by updating the Raspbian software. There were obviously a bug in the version I was running.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after hearing the sound in the video -  it seems like a general problem with the Raspberry Pi.

I just leave this in here for the reference to the video in the comments.

*Well this I'm just guessing without hearing the noise.
But I know from digital audio workstation programs that they are always fading in sound when they start with a sample or wave file and fading out when they are done with that.
I guess your text to voice is generating or assembling these sounds. When you are changing from one file to the other and there is some static or different dc level in these files (or your generated sounds) this could generate some noise.
These are just some random stabs without knowing more details.*

Comment: If you have a look at this video. This guy is doing what I would like to do and he has the same glitch sound. Forward to 3:18 in the video and listen: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=br-xyW8iccg&feature=fvsr

Comment: I get the same glitch sound when I play a wav-file with aplay linux software.